# October CMS Frontend ajax filtering issue(Uncaught TypeError: $form.request is not a function)

Tags: jquery, ajax, octobercms

I am attempting to add a price filter in my october cms project with ajax on frontend. I am getting an error of (Uncaught TypeError: $form.request is not a function) whenever my js code runs.

```
$(function () {

$('.min_gp').on('change', function(){
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $form.request();
});

});
```

I have done it by watching a tutorial from youtube. I don't understand why I am getting this error and how to resolve it.
`

Comment: please share your HTML code as well and please share us how you added your js code to page, we can surely can help you :)

Comment: thanks for your help.
The issue was I did not include {% framework %} to my layout.

Comment: ok good to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK (as far as I know) there is no jQuery funciton called `.request()`. In your code you are calling the jQuery API on the `$form` object. Are you wanting to submit the form when the value changes? If so try this:

```
$('.min_gp').on('change', function(){
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $form.submit();
});
```

(the jQuery docs on form functions for reference: https://api.jquery.com/category/forms/)

However, there is a `.request()` function specific to the OctoberCMS AJAX API but it is called differently and requires you to know the AJAX handler:

```
$('form').request('onCalculate', {
    update: {calcresult: '.result'}
})
```

(see: https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/javascript-api)

--

And for reference you can also submit the form from the element passing a function in the `onchange` attribute on the form element:

```
<select class="form-control price-filter-dropdown min-gp"
     onchange="$(this).closest('form').submit()">
```